# Get root directory of a folder +1

Tags: c#, .net

How can i get the root directory of a folder +1?

Example: 
Input: `C:\Level1\Level2\level3`
output should be:

```
Level1
```

If input is `Level1`
output should be `Level1`

if input is C:\ output should be `empty string`

Is there is a .Net function handles this?

`Directory.GetDirectoryRoot` will always returns `C:\`

Comment: No, there's no built in function to handle this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `Path`-class + `Substring` + `Split` to remove the root and get the top-folder.

```
// your directory:
string dir = @"C:\Level1\Level2\level3";     

// C:\  
string root = Path.GetPathRoot(dir); 

// Level1\Level2\level3:
string pathWithoutRoot = dir.Substring(root.Length);       

// Level1
string firstFolder = pathWithoutRoot.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).First();
```

Another way is using the [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) class and it's [`Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.parent.aspx) property:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Level1\Level2\level3");
string firstFolder = directory.Name;
while (directory.Parent != null && directory.Parent.Name != directory.Root.Name)
{
    firstFolder = directory.Parent.Name;
    directory = directory.Parent;
}
```

However, i would prefer the "lightweight" string methods.

Answer (score 5):

```
string dir = @"C:\foo\bar\woah";
var dirSegments = dir.Split(new char[] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar }, 
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if (dirSegments.Length == 1)
{
    return string.Empty;
}
else
{
    return dirSegments[0] + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + dirSegments[1];
}
```

Comment: Ah we all like a quick-coding challenge don't we? 4 answers all within 4 minutes :)

Comment: You guys are too quick... :P

Comment: You should include the `AltDirectorySeparatorChar` too.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes To be platform agnostic, that would make sense. I was presuming a Windows-only environment.

Comment: @Snixtor ***I*** am the one considering Windows. Only Windows has a AltDirectorySeparatorChar.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Not according to the doco. `DirectorySeparatorChar` is '/' on UNIX and '\' on Win and Mac. While `AltDirectorySeparatorChar` is '\' on UNIX, and '/' on Win and Mac. Apparently `AltDirectorySeparatorChar` can be "set to the same value as DirectorySeparatorChar", though MSDN gives no such example of an environment where that would be the case.

Comment: Mono on Linux has the AltDirectorySeparatorChar as `/`, just like the DirectorySeparatorChar. And that makes total sense because `\\` is *not* a path separator there.

Comment: Interesting. That would suggest mono is contrary to the MSDN documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar.aspx

Comment: Because the MSDN documentation is flat out wrong: \ is a character allowed in file and directory names on Linux, it does not separate anything. Only / acts as a path separator. Implementing it as the docs say would be moronic. On Windows, however, *both* work, and Windows is the reason AltDirectorySeparatorChar exists.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop up using the directory info class using the following structure by adding the code section below into a method

```
string path = "C:\Level1\Level2\level3";
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
while (d.Parent.FullName != Path.GetPathRoot(path))
{
    d = d.Parent;
}
return d.FullName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DirectoryInfo` and a `while` loop.

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
while (info.Parent != null && info.Parent.Parent != null)
    info = info.Parent;
string result = info.FullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, but may not be the best, is to find the position of @"\", and do some manual processing yourself. Below code is not fully tested, just snippet:

```
//var positions = inputString.IndexOfAny(new [] {'\'});  //Original one
//Updated, thanks to Snixtor's implementation 
var positions = inputString.IndexOfAny(new [] {Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}); 
int n=positions.Length;
if(n>=1)
{
     var pos = positions[1];  //The 2nd '\';
     return inputString.SubString(0, pos);
}
return null;
```

Of course, this only works if we are sure we want chop substrings after the 2nd '\'.

Comment: What if the input uses `/`?

Comment: new [] {  '\',   '/',   ...  'any others', ... })

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is the correct way but you do:

```
string s = @"C:\Level1\Level2\Level3";
string foo = s.split(@"\")[1];
```

Not sure whether DirectoryInfo object can get this in a cleaner manner..

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Level1\Level2\Level3");
di.Root;
```

Comment: `di.Root` will return "C:\".

Comment: The second option will not the first, you should be clearer on that one. The first example does exactly what the chap needs.

Comment: I did specifically mention "di.Root", which only occurs in the second option. Your first option will work, *provided* that level exists. It will fail for "C:\" (index out of range) instead of returning an empty string as per OP's wishes.

Answer (score 0):

A happy linq one liner:

```
string level1_2 = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(path) + path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Skip(1).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
```

Comment: Oh, I just noticed the first one fails if it's just @"C:\Level1", so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\a\b\c");
  Func<DirectoryInfo, DirectoryInfo> root = null;
  root = (info) => info.Parent.FullName.EndsWith("\\") ? info : root(info.Parent);
  var rootName = root(di).Name; //#a
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `System.IO.Path` to retrieve the name?

```
MessageBox.Show(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Level1\Level2\Level3")
    )
));
```

This returns `Level 1`.

```
MessageBox.Show(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\")
    )
));
```

This returns empty string.

Comment: How this method is dynamic? it expects a three level tree, with "@"C:\Level1\Level2\Level3\Level4" gives "Level2"